# How to modify behaviour of Imageview in coordinate layout

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want my imageView to disappear when collapse toolbar reach at certain height I have anchored my image to collapsing toolbar its moving with collapsing toolbar but I'm unable to make that imageView to fade out

Like in this [link](https://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/) the FAB disappear as toolbar collapse(The gif under the heading collapsing toolbar and appbar, in the link provided) I want this behaviour on imageview rather FAB

Comment: You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162616/coordinatorlayout-and-layout-behavior-or-image-overlapping this post

Comment: You would have to post some code for us to know what is it that you are doing to solve the above problem so that we can point out where are you going wrong. BTW, if you want something from scratch, you can try this: http://yaronvazana.com/2015/12/28/material-design-collapsing-toolbar-with-image/

Comment: like in this link: http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/ the FAB disappear as toolbar collapse(The gif under the heading collapsing toolbar and appbar, in the link provided) I want this behaviour on imageview rather FAB

Answer (score 2):

FAB have a custom [Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html) class for that.

For your ImageView you can use a listener on your AppBarLayout, for example :

In your activity:

```
AppBarLayout appbarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbarlayoutid);
appbarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener( new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            float percentage = (appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()-(float)Math.abs(verticalOffset))/appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();

            if(percentage < 0.3) {
                 mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            } else if(percentage > 0.7) {
                 mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so we can't create custom behavior for imageview too?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no similar class for imageview, but if i inderstood properly your issue, the code above should work. Let me know.